# Product Image resolution issue woocommerce / wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Getting an issue with either Wordpress or Woocommerce.

Yesterday I updated Woocommerce as I was installing a new theme. The issue I have come across now is that I can't change the image resolution to be better quality on the product page.

So, just to give a quick run down, I have installed a new theme and updated woocommerce.

But for some reason the image quality is rubbish, For example, this page https://www.gogadgets.ie/shop/android-tv-boxes/mxq-android-tv-box/

The image is of low quality even though the original uploaded is 750x750px. I went to the settings for Woocommerce and changed the dimensions - funnily enough when I save the image size settings **they revert back to the default setting which is 433x325px.**

Could this be a database issue or is there any type of file I can upload to the site that could override any image dimension settings for the main product image?

I know the css is good for the theme as there is no quality issues on their demo site. 
Hope I have given enough information and this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: and just to clarify, I am not trying to make the overall image bigger, just the resolution.

Comment: Install the plugin force regenerate thumbnails and run in once to regenerate all of your thumbnails. Setting a new thumbnail size does not change the thumbnails allready uploaded.

Comment: I have the plugin installed and all it did was make the image bigger inside the frame. The image settings won't save in Woocommerce either.

Comment: I'm sorry for off-topic question, but may I ask how do you manage menus on your site's footer? Are they hard-coded or there's a special plugin to sort and handle them?

Answer (score 0):

If the woocommerce image size settings are automatically overridden, then it might be because they are overridden from the theme settings. Media Center is a good theme. You might be able to find the settings within
**'MCOptions > Shop > Product Item Settings`**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the only settings there is "Hard Crop Images ?"

Comment: i tried turning on hard crop images and didn't work. thanks for your help though.